# Organize or group data from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I'm having difficulty trying to group and sort for a particular need. Here is the array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Joe Smith 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => 3 
            [1] => 9 
        ) 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => John Doe 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => 6 
            [1] => 12 
        ) 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => Jack Frost 
        [1] => Array ( 
            [0] => 2 
            [1] => 4 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

What I want to do is sort the numbers from smallest to shortest (i.e. 2,3,4,6,9,12), but also keep the names associated with those numbers. For example:

```
2 (Jack Frost),
3 (Joe Smith),
4 (Jack Frost),
6 (John Doe),
9 (Joe Smith),
12 (John Doe)
```

Any ideas how to sort by number and keep the names together? Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the PHP code I've used to list the numbers in order:

```
$users = get_users();

$names = array();
$days = array();

foreach( $users as $user ) {
    $names[] = $user->display_name;
    $days[] = $user->member_day;
}

$result = array_map( null, $names, $days );

$mdays = array();
foreach( $days as $d ) {
    foreach( $d as $d2) {
        $mdays[] = $d2;
    }
}

for( $i; $i<=31; $i++ ) {
    if( in_array($i, $mdays) ) {
        echo $i . '<br>';
    }
}
```

In the above code, `$result` prints out the above Array. Also, the `for` loop sorts the "days".

The end goal is to have 31 blocks and fill in the block by number with the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like as

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value[1] as $v) {
        $result[$v] = $value[0];
    }
}
ksort($result);
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [2] => Jack Frost
    [3] => Joe Smith
    [4] => Jack Frost
    [6] => John Doe
    [9] => Joe Smith
    [12] => John Doe
)
```

> Note: This'll work fine till none of the array array contains the same key

Comment: That worked perfectly. You can see the results here: (http://katart.biz/ppt/testpage/). Now I have to figure out this undefined offset error.

Comment: Try to use `isset` wherever you were calling that array

Comment: Since I'm using a `for` loop to cycle through 31 days, I used `if( isset($roster[$i]) ) { $name = $roster[$i]; }` to get this to work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work, and at the end you can soert you array

```
$final_array=array();
foreach (array as $arr){
  foreach($arr as $aaa){
    $final_array[]=array($aaa,$arr[0])
  }
}
```